# Permutate image dimensions in Python

Tags: python

I want to do the equivalent of `permute.m` in MATLAB for an array in Python.

For example: `A` is a 4D array with the shape `(50,50,3,100)` that I want to make `(100,50,50,3)`. In MATLAB this can be done:

```
B = permute(A,[4,1,2,3])
```

How to do this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is to *transpose* your array, Numpy arrays have a `.transpose` method, you have just to remember that Python counts from zero

```
b = a.transpose((3,0,1,2))
```

(*note that the method takes a single argument, a tuple describing the permutation of the axes*).

Comment: I have used small letters because it is customary to reserve capitals to `class`es and, to a lesser extent, to constants.

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy you can use swapaxes

```
numpy.swapaxes(a, axis1, axis2)


# equivalent to [4,1,2,3]
B = A.swapaxes(3,0).swapaxes(1,3).swapaxes(2,3)
```

or transpose

```
B = A.transpose((3,0,1,2))
```

Otherwise you can use np.moveaxis

```
B = A.moveaxis([0, 1, 2, 3], [-3, -2, -1, -4])
```